# Component doesn't work after/with build, but works fine if it is within the same package

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a mono repo project bootstrapped with `lerna` and one of the packages is a component library, let's call it `packages/our-component-library`.

This component library is used in another package which is a NextJS front end app, let's call it `packages/our-frontend-stuff` and one of the Component files there imports `SomeComponent` from `our-component-library` such as :

`import SomeComponent from '@our-name-space/our-component-library'`

Whenever there is a change in the component library(uses Storybook etc.) I have to do `yarn build` from the component library directory.

Inside of one of the components in 'packages/our-component-library' there is a select component from a `react-select` npm module, which doesn't show props and the weird thing if I copy-paste `/src` of the `our-component-library` package to `packages/our-frontend-stuff/src/`, it would start working and show the prop. I think the issue is related to `react-select` probably, but not sure. Appreciate hearing your thoughts

Note: this NextJS project uses typescript and the latest NextJS version 12

Comment: Does the `npm run build` shows the same issue on local?

Comment: @illiachill apologies I had to specify,  I am `yarn` and yes locally same issue with `yarn build`